# Dependant Drop Down List With Search Box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have three tables:

1. Countries [CountryId, CountryName]
2. States [StateId, StateName, CountryId_FK]
3. Cities [CityId, CityName, CityInfo, StateId_FK]

On my html form, I am able to list Countries & States in two dependant drop downs using PHP & Ajax. The States drop down is dependant on the country drop down which is working fine.

However, I am stuck trying to have the input text box search for a city based on the selection of the state and if the city exists, it should display the CityName and CityInfo preferably to a table.

Below is the php code where I think I am stuck at.

```
    if (isset($_POST['StateId'])){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblCities WHERE StateId=".$_POST['StateId'] ;
        // GET Search here???
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
        }
```

NOTE: I can echo results into a table just fine but I want to SEARCH for a city first before displaying the match.

ajaxdata.php

```
if (isset($_POST['CountryId'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblStates WHERE CountryId=".$_POST['CountryId'];
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        echo '<option selected disabled value="">Select States</option>';
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value='.$row['StateId'].'>'.$row['StateName'].'</option>';
            json_encode($row, $name);
        }
    }else {
        echo '<option>No State Found!</option>';

    }
}
```

functions.js

```
function FetchCountry(id){
    $('#countries').html(''); 
    $('#states').html(''<option selected disabled>Select State</option>');
    $.ajax ({
        type:'post',
        url:'ajaxdata.php',
        data : {CountryId : id},
        success : function(data,){
            $('#states').html(data);
            console.log(data); //Log data
        }
    });
}
function FetchStates(id){
    $('#cities').html('');
    $.ajax ({
        type:'post',
        url:'ajaxdata.php',
        data : {StateId : id},
        success : function(data,){
            $('#cities').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
include "database.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblCountries";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
//CSS/JS/JQUERY here
 <head>
  <script src="functions.js">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <form method="POST">
     <select id="countries" onchange="FetchCountries(this.value)">
      <option selected disabled>Select Country</option>
        <php?
             if ($result->num_rows > 0){
             while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             echo '<option value='.$row['CountryId'].'>'.$row['CountryName'].'</option>';
            }
          }
         ?>
     <select id="states" onchange="FetchStates(this.value)">
      <option selected disabled>Select State</option>
     <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control"></input>
     <button class="btn-Search" name="submit" type="submit"></button>
  </form>
  </div>
  <--Results Area -->
   <div class="container">
    <table id="cities"></table>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also show the PHP AJAX code that you have tried. It will be good if you show some form or box what exactly you want to show on what basis.

Comment: @JohnDoe, I have included the codes

Answer (score 0):

You should change your sql statements to this:

```sql
$query="SELECT Cities.CityId, Cities.CityName, Cities.CityInfo
FROM Cities
JOIN States ON Cities.StatedId_FK=States.StatedId
WHERE States.StatedId = '".$_POST['StateId']."'";
```

```sql
$query="SELECT Countries.CountryId, Countries.CountryName
FROM Countries
JOIN States ON Countries.CountryId=States.CountryId_FK
WHERE CountryId='".$_POST['CountryId']."'";
```

See this tutorial:
https://www.php-einfach.de/mysql-tutorial/mysql-left-join/

you can do something like this:

```html
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="showCities(this.value) class="form-control"></input>
```

And then make a function showCities like function FetchStates.

Comment: Beatu, after returning $query how do I use the text input box to search for a city name in $query?